# Oracle PL/SQL Parallel execution

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to write something about PL/SQL Parallel execution for a homework and i don't find a good tutorial that talks about this (i just need material about `parallel` execution of PL/SQL). Please, if you know some materials share them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576802/can-we-use-threading-in-pl-sql

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answer:  parallel pipelined PL/SQL functions.  Check it out here (thanks Tom!) http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:39946845137685

Answer (score -1):

usually a dbms will not do parallel execution for one sql/plsql because it will handle concurrent users. so work load balancing is usually based on parallel sessions an not on single executions. newer the less you can use some tricks to get parallel execution
1.) use union all 
2.) use partitioned tables and the parallel hint
3.) use dbms_jobs for parallel processing

For details just google these keywords or search trough asktom

Comment: The first sentence isn't correct, the parallel execution you mention takes place for "one" sql/plsql.  Ex:  select /*+PARALLEL(a,4)*/ * from table.  Rephrase maybe?