# Parallel Execution of Stored Procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g, oracle9i

I have one package contains many Stored Procedure for populating diffrent tables.
This package is being called at the time of Uplaod of one Excel file.
Now suppose i have five procedure SP1,SP2,SP3,SP4,SP5 inside a package PKG

```
    Create or replace  package PKG
declare
    begin 
    sp1;
    sp2;--shd run without waiting for SP1 to get finish..
    sp3;--shd run without waiting for SP2 to get finish..
    sp4;--shd run without waiting for SP3 to get finish..
    sp5;--shd run without waiting for SP4 to get finish..
    end;
```

Now what i want is to execute all SP together tat means SP2 shd not wait for SP1 to get complete..
Is there any way to do like this "parallel execution of procedures"..

I am using PL/SQL oracle 9i/10g

Thanks

Comment: you may find an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576802/can-we-use-threading-in-pl-sql

Comment: check here http://www.williamrobertson.net/feed/2007/10/parallel-plsql-launcher.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up packages dependencies and execution depenndencies...

There are many ways that will allow you to run some procedures in parallel:

- You can just open many sessions and run one procedure from each
- Another approach will be to use dbms_job to run the procedures in the background

Do you need the client to be notified when the process end?

More information is needed if this is not sufficient.