# How do I run procedures in parallel within an Oracle package?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, parallel-processing, package

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can We use threading in PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576802/can-we-use-threading-in-pl-sql)

I have a package that contains a bunch of procedures all bundled together; the package is intended to be executed from a main proc call that then calls the others.  Within the private procs, I have queries that update (via merge) a table.  While these proc/queries update the same table, they don't update the same columns.  I'd like to be able to call these procs in parallel to gain performance as they shouldn't interfere with each other.  How would I do that?

Comment: Looks like this has already been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576802/can-we-use-threading-in-pl-sql

Comment: Do they update the same rows of the table?  Since locking is done at a row level, it doesn't matter whether the procedures are updating the same columns.  If they are updating the same rows, you'll end up with row-level lock contention and won't gain anything from parallelism.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, yeah they do.  I guess that's the answer then?  If the table locks on a row-level, then, unless you chunk up the the updates, you can't achieve parallelism.  's too bad.  I did think the DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE looked interesting, though.