# SQL Query return a value if running more than x seconds?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to terminate an executing query and return a specific value (e.g `return value = 1` ) if a SQL query runs for longer than X seconds?

Could you please give a concrete example with a basic query. For example in SQL:

```
select * from test
```

If this query is taking more than 10 seconds to execute, it should return: 1 as the result.

I am using SQL management studio.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name :- Can you check pls my ans is valid or not??

Comment: What back-end language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it,s possible. You can use **Threading**

Look here some examples

[Can We use threading in PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576802/can-we-use-threading-in-pl-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DBPROP COMMANDTIMEOUT` to specify the timeout and use a TRY CATH on your client because, in SQL, the connection timeout can not be recovered.

Comment: For which DBMS does your answer apply?

Comment: Apply for  SQL SERVER

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.. i have put custom logic for that..

```
declare @Starttime datetime=getdate()


select * into #tmp from test


if DATEDIFF(SECOND,@Starttime,getdate()) >10
begin
   select 1
end
```