# How do I execute multiple Oracle stored procedures concurrently / in parallel for better performance?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, cursors

I want to be able to execute several independent stored procedures which can contain arguments of the type `NUMBER (IN)`, `VARCHAR (IN)` and `CURSOR (OUT)`.

The results of the CURSOR output is then used by a .NET application to produce a JSON structure as an API response to an HTTP request. Subsecond performance is expected and I'm exploring areas of optimisation apart from the obvious.

`dbms_scheduler` approach was tried but unclear on how CURSOR type can be used.
Following steps, were experimented without definite results.

```
/* Steps tried.
1. dbms_scheduler.create_program
2. dbms_scheduler.define_program_argument
3. dbms_scheduler.create_job
4. dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value
*/

-- Parent proc
PROCEDURE get_all_customer_details_prc (
    i_customer_id               IN customer.pecustomer_id%TYPE,
    i_year                      IN customer_instance.year_value%TYPE,
    oc_customer_details_data    OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    oc_customer_purchase_data   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)

BEGIN
-- Can the two procedures at the same time, so that the 
-- get_customer_details_prc returns when the longest taking proc finalises?  

-- Child proc 1
PROCEDURE get_customer_details_prc (
    i_customer_id,      
    oc_customer_details_data 
);

-- Child proc 2
PROCEDURE get_customer_purchase_details_prc (
    i_customer_id,      
    i_year,      
    oc_customer_purchase_data      
);
END;
```

Comment: I think most people would use DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE. This Ask Tom article has a detailed walkthrough. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4248554900346593542

Comment: But also check out the first answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576802/can-we-use-threading-in-pl-sql

Comment: @kfinity, thank you. I'm unclear on how a CURSOR can be used with  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE. Do you mind providing a snippet based on [get_all_customer_details_prc] parent proc that will need to call the two child procs [get_customer_details_prc] and [get_customer_purchase_details_prc] in parallel?